# Update SQL Server table from Excel data

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

Currently I am trying to import data from an Excel 2007 workbook into a SQL Server 2008 R2 table 'test'.

The import works perfectly, however, the data on the workbook is changed constantly and needs to be imported every ten mins or so.

When I re-run the import, SQL Server just copies all the data and ends up with identical duplicates - how can I go about the import in such a way that it will add only new and `UPDATE` changed columns for old data?

I have tried to import to another table and copy over only the new data (not what I require and did not work).

Also, the following seems promising, however, not sure it will do what I require...

```
--Update existing, add missing
MERGE INTO dbo.tbl_Customers AS C
USING dbo.tbl_CustomersTemp AS CT ON C.CustID = CT.CustID

WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE 
        SET
          C.CompanyName = CT.CompanyName,
          C.Phone = CT.Phone

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
     INSERT (CustID, CompanyName, Phone)
     VALUES (CT.CustID, CT.CompanyName, CT.Phone)
```

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated - please let me know if there is anything I have missed.

Thanks

Comment: MERGE can be used to update existing and add new.  Have you tried it?

Comment: I have but I know the basics about SQL and am not sure of the correct syntax or command to do what I require.

Comment: It looks to me that you are on the right track. This query matches your description. You can test it using a handful or records. Once confident you can scale up.

Comment: I have managed to get it to work now :)

The only problem I am left with is when importing from Excel, it adds the data into the dummy table, then when I run the script to merge, it throws the following error:

Comment: Msg 8672, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.

Comment: I can work around this by deleting all data from the dummy table before an import, but is there a neater way?

Comment: I have managed to resolve the above as well by changing my command to:

    MERGE INTO dbo.tbl_customers AS C
    USING (SELECT TOP 1 [A], [B], [C]...etc

Answer (score 0):

```
MERGE INTO dbo.test AS C
USING (SELECT TOP 1 [A], [B], [C], [D], [E], [F], [G], [H], [I] FROM dbo.test_import) AS CT 

ON C.[A] = CT.[A]

WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE 
     SET
       C.[B] = CT.[B],
       C.[C] = CT.[C],
       C.[D] = CT.[D],
       C.[E] = CT.[E],
       C.[F] = CT.[F],
       C.[G] = CT.[G],
       C.[H] = CT.[H],
       C.[I] = CT.[I]     

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT ([A], [B], [C], [D], [E], [F], [G], [H], [I])
    VALUES (CT.[A], CT.[B], CT.[C], CT.[D], CT.[E], CT.[F], CT.[G], CT.[H], CT.[I]);
```